# Trouble with Wordpress Custom Fields in Php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-fields

I've been having trouble properly outputting the directory for images in a slider using Custom Fields. The code I'm using is following:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    //path or directory where the images are stored
    $directory = "echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'directory', true)";

    //read all files with a .jpg extension
    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

    //output the required HTML code to display the images in the gallery
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        echo '<div class="content"><div><a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="120" height="80" alt="this is a test" class="thumb" /></a></div></div>'."\n";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

The value I want to dynamically output is the $directory = "", where it would normally be something like $directory = "images/product1/". I have my custom field 'directory' set as images/product1/. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit gapple. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with this line:

```
$directory = "echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'directory', true)";
```

will result in trying to glob like this:

```
glob("echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'directory', true)*.jpg");
```

which is obviously invalid.

Instead you should actually be calling the `get_post_meta()` function

```
$directory = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'directory', true);
```

Comment: Perfect gapple, worked great for me. Thanks again for the help!